# Labelling an axis in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Can anyone help me label z layers (years in my case) along z-axis shown in image please? The Year labels that appear now on this image is just my text added onto the screenshot just to show what I am wishing to achieve.

Labels are shown in ArcScene in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eyFAIZrNGo)

[image]

Comment: You are out of luck. Labeling as such doesn't exist in scene

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eyFAIZrNGo this guy actually has labelled the layers on z-axis. cool, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on the 3D Graphics toolbar, adjust some of the default text graphics properties before you add a label so that it is added large enough to see/find.

[image]

Select the 3D Text tool

[image]

Use the 3D Text tool to click on the *feature* you want to label, and type in the label you wish to display.  Adjust the label properties for orientation and size.

I've created a quick 3D layer to demonstrate the result:

[image]

This 3D Text will rotate with your scene as it does in the linked video.  Unless the scene is using a third-party add-in for labels, I believe this is the only way to do it in ArcScene.

Comment: Have updated to include sample result

Comment: Wow, awesome, it worked like a magic. Genius. Do you know why Arcscene automatically shuts down every time i try to export the scene?  Is it because I have 19 separate layers for each year? making my file big?

Comment: @Maggie I image that's probably the case, but it might be worthy of a new question.  Before that you should probably test on different sized scenes and see if it makes a difference