# Create Space Time Cube in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, space-time-cube

I am looking for GIS software that performs space time cube visualization.

I am studying the incidence of dengue at data points that represent a collection of [ovitraps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovitrap) (traps to catch the mosquitoes' eggs), with an attribute representing the number of eggs caught each week at that location.

The data structure are multipoints, so when a select a specific point (an geolocated ovitrap), multiple regists are selected and these include the number of eggs caught in a specific week.

My goal is use a space time cube to see the number of eggs caught every week in different ovitraps, as shown in the image below. I want to analyze spatio-temporal patterns.

I've tried the [space time cube from arcgis](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/create-space-time-cube.htm), but it just works with the number of points in the space, for example, the number of geolocated people infected in some region.

I have a set of points (ovitraps) that catch mosquito eggs. They are not  generated by a random process like in the example above, but were placed by people with the goal to monitor mosquito activity at a specific places through time.

[image]

Comment: What GIS software do you use for other purposes? Have you tried searching for it along with 'space time cube'?

Comment: I try to used the space time cube from arcgis,  but i can not do what a i want because the arcgis space time cube tool just work with the amoung of points in the space, for example, the geolocated people infected in some region.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain that.

Comment: I try to used the space time cube from arcgis,  but i can not do what a i want because the arcgis space time cube tool just work with the amoung of points in the space, for example, the geolocated people infected in some region. What a have is a  set of points (ovitraps) that catch mosquitoes eggs. so they are not random, they were placed by people with the goal to monitorize the mosquitoes activity in a specfific places by time.

Comment: Please clarify "The data structure are multipoints, so when a select a specific point (an geolocated ovitrap), multiple regists are selected and these include the number of eggs caught in a specific week."

Comment: By multipoints, are you saying that at a specific ovitrap location, you have an individual point for every week with the attribute being the number of caught mosquitoes? Thus having a bunch of points all in exactly the same place, instead of a single point for the location which then has a separate attribute for each week?

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192403/how-to-label-an-axis-in-arcscene/192413#192413